# Force Email Verification For New Signup With Google Identity Toolkit

Tags: google-identity-toolkit

For google identity toolkit, does anybody know how to force email verification of a password account (rather than through a provider i.e. google, facebook etc) immediately after signup?

I've come across this response from google -- https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-identity-toolkit/VQ09lFJNkWk -- but doesn't seem to mention the specific functions we should be focused on

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes emails from other providers aren't verified, so you might want to force verification for all authentication types. Are you using one of the Gitkit libraries? If so, you can just get the verification link by calling the appropriate function. In the PHP library, it's `getEmailVerificationLink($email)`.

Have your login handler file check to see if the email is verified. If it's not, you can display a message letting the user know that a verification message is on the way. Then, get the link, and send the email. Let me know if you're using the PHP library and I can help further if needed.

Comment: Thanks! Was originally wondering if there's a fuller function that handles verification including showing a message that the account isn't verified... looks like needs to be handled by the app seperately -- am now using GetEmailVerificationLink in the python version of the gitkitclient library